# Find words starting with hashtag in Scala/Java

Tags: java, regex, scala

I'm trying to write regex that will split all words starting with hashtag.
For example in following text it should :

```scala
val regex = "???".r

val text = "#shouldMatch1 #shouldMatch2 notMatch nope#shouldMatch3 nooope()#shouldMatch4"

regex.split(text).toList shouldBe List("#shouldMatch1", "#shouldMatch2", "#shouldMatch3", "#shouldMatch4")
```

The closes that I could get is `val regex:  Regex = "[^#\\w+]".r`, but it splits a litte bit more:

```
List("#shouldMatch1", "#shouldMatch2", "notMatch", "nope#shouldMatch3", "nooope", "#shouldMatch4")
```

So in some cases it finds words that do not start with hashtag.
Do you have any idea or guidance how I should write proper expression?

Code was written in Scala but should the similar in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`findAllIn`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findAllIn(source:CharSequence):scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator) with a regex like `#\w+`:

```scala
val regex = """#\w+""".r
val text = "#shouldMatch1 #shouldMatch2 notMatch nope#shouldMatch3 nooope()#shouldMatch4"
println(regex.findAllIn(text).toList)
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/BZ0UIu).

The hashtag matching pattern can be different, there are a lot of variations. Here are some of them:

- `#\w+` - if the hashtags can contain only word chars
- `#[\w-]+` - if the hashtags can contain only word and hyphen chars
- `#\S+` - if the hashtags contain any amount of one or more non-whitespace chars after `#`
- `#\S+\b` - if the hashtags contain any amount of one or more non-whitespace chars after `#` but you want it to stop before the final sequence of non-word chars (like a comma, etc)
- `(?<!\S)#\S+` - if the hashtags contain any amount of one or more non-whitespace chars after `#`, but before `#`, there can only be whitespace or start of string.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome and detailed answer. Indeed it was just a different method needed.